# How to setup HTTPS connection with Walmart Electrode

Tags: walmart-electrode

It sounds trivial, but I've spent a lot of time trying to find the answer.

How do you tell Electrode Server to create https connection? How to configure it properly?

Their PWA examples never mention this, and yet PWA would not work without https.

Answer (score 0):

You would pass a connection object in the config/default.json or config/production.json.

provide tls properties ( provide the private key and cert here ). Check this out: [Migrating HTTPS server from Express to Hapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38530079/migrating-https-server-from-express-to-hapi)

Comment: I've ended up terminating https at the load balancer (DIgital Ocean). Https works now, bot PWA still does not - unhappy about something.